# Python - server run

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am new to python and an writing a simple code where I use speech recognition get a voice response whenever I call the code. However, python does not ends its running. How can I keep the python file running forever? I tried using launchctl, while loop and also nohup. But nothing works... I want it to run like nodemon server where it stops only if I want give the command to stop it. Here's my code...

```
engine = p.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')  
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)  

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    text = r.listen(source)

    try:
        recognized_text = r.recognize_google(text)
        print(recognized_text)
        if recognized_text == '':
            print('Do nothing')
        elif recognized_text == 'Hello'
            engine.say("Hi there!")
            engine.runAndWait()
        else:
            print('Did not work: ' + recognized_text)
            engine.say('Cannot understand you')
    except sr.UnknownValueError as e:
        print("Boss not speaking")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("request error")
```

Comment: please add your `sr` import in the code

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there are some things that you can do to improve this code. For example, your `else:` and `sr.UnknownValueError` do the same thing, so there is no need for both. I would advice getting rid of the `else:`. Secondly, there is no need for the `as e` at the end of your except statements because you aren't ever calling `e`, so it is basically useless.

Also, it would be much better if you made a function called `speak` or something else that runs `engine.say(audio)` and `engine.runAndWait()` together.

Now to the main problem. If you want this code to run forever, then all you need is a while loop. Then, you can simply call `break` to end the while loop.

This is how I did it:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', rate-70)

volume = engine.getProperty('volume')
engine.setProperty('volume', 1)

#A Single Function
def speak(audio):
    print(audio)
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

i=0
n = 0

while (i<1):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        n=(n+1)
        print("Waiting For Voice Input...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
                                                   # interprete audio (Google Speech Recognition)
    try:
        s = (r.recognize_google(audio))
        message = (s.lower())

        if message == '':
            print('Do nothing')
        elif message == 'hello':
            speak("Hi there!")
        elif ('goodbye') in message or ('power off') in message or ('bye') in message:
            speak("goodbye")
            break

    # exceptions
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Retry")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results$; {0}".format(e))
        try:
            speak("Sir Bad Signal")
        except:
            print("Sir Bad Signal")
```

All you really need is a condition that will always be True. I set a variable called i to 0, and then ran the while loop as long as i was less than 1, which is always true because i is set to 0.

To end the code, I use `break` whenever the message was goodbye. Alternatively, you could change i to be 1, which would also work as i would no longer be less than 1.

Also, I converted the users input into lowercase. Therefore, you will need to check if the message is equal to a lowercase string. For example, `elif message == 'Hello'` won't work because the message is lowercase, but `elif message == 'hello'` will work.

Finally, I adjusted the microphone to ambient noise because it would make it easier for the microphone to understand what you're saying.